# ordering keys from Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I saw [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value) and the answers, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I tried alll variants of the values in the Object and sort, but it doesn't seem to work. I want to get a list ordered on the keys (not their values) in the objects (the, in this example 2 objects are in in a json):

d3.json:

```
{
"TEST1":    {"purchase": ["yes", 2], "safety": ["no", 3], "quality": ["Carried by the husk", 1], "name": ["Eggs!", 0]},
"TEST2":    {"purchase": "yes", "safety": "no", "quality": "Carried by the husk", "name": "0"}
```

}

And the JavaScript:

```
d3.json("d3.json", function(root) {

  for (key in root) {
      console.log(root[key]);
      var test = root[key];
      var list = Object.keys(test).sort(function(a,b){ return test[a]-test[b] })
      console.log(list);
  }
});
```

EDIT: Apologies, I wasn't clear on the expected results: I was looking for the keys sorted, but return with their values as the answer of dlopez did.

Comment: What are expected results?

Comment: Good question, i edited :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
var sortedByKeys = Object.keys(root)
    .sort(function(a,b) { return a - b; })
    .reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        prev[curr] = root[curr];
        return prev;
    }, {});
```

Comment: Thanks! Especially for interpreting the desired results :) In ended up needing an extra step (starting of with (for key in root), your code only sort the objects in the root, not the ones in root[key]) and I could leave out the sort-function (as stated by aromatt):
 
for (key in root) {
 var sortedByKeys = Object.keys(root[key])
     .sort()
     .reduce(function(prev, curr) {
         prev[curr] = root[key][curr];
         return prev;
     }, {});
 console.log(sortedByKeys);
}

Answer (score 1):

By using `test[a] - test[b]` in the sort call back function, you sort by the property values, not the keys. To sort by the keys you can use this:

```
  var list = Object.keys(test).sort(function(a,b){ return a.localeCompare(b) })
```

which is the default sorting order, so:

```
  var list = Object.keys(test).sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use
`var list = Object.keys(test).sort();`